# PHP header attach AVI-file

Tags: php, download, content-type, attachment, avi

I'm trying to make a PHP script to download an AVI-file. The file is on my server and I want to send it to the user. I have made the following script but when I run it, I will only get a 0 KB large AVI file.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
$file_path = "downloads/test.avi";

// Get filename
$filename = explode("/", $file_path);
$filename = $filename[count($filename)-1];

if(file_exists($file_path)) {
    $file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_path, "."), 1));

    // This will set the Content-Type to the appropriate setting for the file
    switch($file_extension) {
        case "pdf":
            $ctype = "application/pdf";
            break;
        case "exe":
            $ctype = "application/octet-stream";
            break;
        case "zip":
            $ctype = "application/zip";
            break;
        case "doc":
            $ctype = "application/msword";
            break;
        case "xls":
            $ctype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            break;
        case "ppt":
            $ctype = "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint";
            break;
        case "gif":
            $ctype = "image/gif";
            break;
        case "png":
            $ctype = "image/png";
            break;
        case "jpeg":
            $ctype = "image/jpg";
            break;
        case "jpg":
            $ctype = "image/jpg";
            break;
        case "mp3":
            $ctype = "audio/mpeg";
            break;
        case "wav":
            $ctype = "audio/x-wav";
            break;
        case "mpeg":
            $ctype = "video/mpeg";
            break;
        case "mpg":
            $ctype = "video/mpeg";
            break;
        case "mpe":
            $ctype = "video/mpeg";
            break;
        case "mov":
            $ctype = "video/quicktime";
            break;
        case "avi":
            $ctype = "video/x-msvideo";
            break;
        case "src":
            $ctype = "plain/text";
            break;
        default:
            $ctype = "application/force-download";
    }

    $filesize = filesize($file_path);

    // Set content type
    header("Content-type: " . $ctype);

    // Download file
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\"");

    // Set size of file
    header("Content-Length: " . $filesize);

    readfile($file_path);
```

This is what I get from LiveHTTPHeaders in Firefox (for some reason `Content-Length`is zero):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 17 Jul 2011 14:34:24 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.6 mod_auth_kerb/5.3 PHP/5.2.17 mod_fcgid/2.3.5
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.avi"
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: video/x-msvideo
```

You may want to try the site out yourself at http://snuzzer.dk/nas/client.php

Comment: Just a note: Use an array with keys as file-extension and values as their mime-type. Will reduce your code and is maybe easier to edit

Comment: readfile() returns the number of bytes read, could you check that it really reads the file? Could be permissions problem.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line before `readfile()`:

```
 header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file_path));
```

Comment: As I just wrote to @alex, the result is exactly the same with or without `Content-Length`

Comment: I just tried using LiveHTTPHeaders in Firefox and for some reason Firefox will not open the page when I use `readfile()` in it and LiveHTTPHeaders says that `Content-Length` is 0. Please check my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Test it,i think this will work!

```
header ( "Pragma: public" );
header ( "Expires: 0" );
header ( "Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" );
header ( "Content-Type: application/force-download" );
header ( "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" );
header ( "Content-Type: application/download" );
header ( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $file_path . "\";" );
header ( "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary " );
header ( "Content-type: " . $ctype);

$chunksize = 1 * (1024 * 1024); // how many bytes per chunk 
if ($size > $chunksize) { 
  $handle = fopen($file_path, 'rb'); 
  $buffer = ''; 
  while (!feof($handle)) { 
    $buffer = fread($handle, $chunksize); 
    echo $buffer; 
    ob_flush(); 
    flush(); 
  } 
  fclose($handle); 
  exit();
```