# PHP only half of file is downloaded

Tags: php, file, download, client, attachment

I have some larger files which I need to share with people and to make it easier for them (and for the fun of developing it) I am developing a small browser-based FTP client. It's nothing more than the [standard functions](http://php.net/ftp) in PHP.

[Yesterday I made a question here about how to download AVI files to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724257/php-header-attach-avi-file) and I found [this function](http://www.awesomephp.com/?Tutorials*16/Download-file-with-resume,-stream-and-speed-options.html) to do so:

```
<?php 

/* Tutorial by AwesomePHP.com -> www.AwesomePHP.com */ 
/* Function: download with resume/speed/stream options */ 

/* 
    Parametrs: downloadFile(File Location, File Name, 
    max speed, is streaming   
    If streaming - movies will show as movies, images as images 
    instead of download prompt 
*/ 
     
function downloadFile($fileLocation,$fileName,$maxSpeed = 100,$doStream =
false){ 
    if (connection_status()!=0) return(false); 
    $extension = strtolower(end(explode('.',$fileName))); 

    /* List of File Types */ 
    $fileTypes['swf'] = 'application/x-shockwave-flash'; 
    $fileTypes['pdf'] = 'application/pdf'; 
    $fileTypes['exe'] = 'application/octet-stream'; 
    $fileTypes['zip'] = 'application/zip'; 
    $fileTypes['doc'] = 'application/msword'; 
    $fileTypes['xls'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel'; 
    $fileTypes['ppt'] = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint'; 
    $fileTypes['gif'] = 'image/gif'; 
    $fileTypes['png'] = 'image/png'; 
    $fileTypes['jpeg'] = 'image/jpg'; 
    $fileTypes['jpg'] = 'image/jpg'; 
    $fileTypes['rar'] = 'application/rar';     
     
    $fileTypes['ra'] = 'audio/x-pn-realaudio'; 
    $fileTypes['ram'] = 'audio/x-pn-realaudio'; 
    $fileTypes['ogg'] = 'audio/x-pn-realaudio'; 
     
    $fileTypes['wav'] = 'video/x-msvideo'; 
    $fileTypes['wmv'] = 'video/x-msvideo'; 
    $fileTypes['avi'] = 'video/x-msvideo'; 
    $fileTypes['asf'] = 'video/x-msvideo'; 
    $fileTypes['divx'] = 'video/x-msvideo'; 

    $fileTypes['mp3'] = 'audio/mpeg'; 
    $fileTypes['mp4'] = 'audio/mpeg'; 
    $fileTypes['mpeg'] = 'video/mpeg'; 
    $fileTypes['mpg'] = 'video/mpeg'; 
    $fileTypes['mpe'] = 'video/mpeg'; 
    $fileTypes['mov'] = 'video/quicktime'; 
    $fileTypes['swf'] = 'video/quicktime'; 
    $fileTypes['3gp'] = 'video/quicktime'; 
    $fileTypes['m4a'] = 'video/quicktime'; 
    $fileTypes['aac'] = 'video/quicktime'; 
    $fileTypes['m3u'] = 'video/quicktime'; 

    $contentType = $fileTypes[$extension]; 
     
     
    header("Cache-Control: public"); 
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n"); 
    header('Content-Type: $contentType'); 

    $contentDisposition = 'attachment'; 
     
    if($doStream == true){ 
        /* extensions to stream */ 
        $array_listen = array('mp3','m3u','m4a','mid','ogg','ra','ram','wm', 
        'wav','wma','aac','3gp','avi','mov','mp4','mpeg','mpg','swf','wmv','divx','asf'); 
        if(in_array($extension,$array_listen)){  
            $contentDisposition = 'inline'; 
        } 
    } 

    if (strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "MSIE")) { 
        $fileName= preg_replace('/\./', '%2e', $fileName, substr_count($fileName,
'.') - 1); 
        header("Content-Disposition: $contentDisposition;
filename=\"$fileName\""); 
    } else { 
        header("Content-Disposition: $contentDisposition;
filename=\"$fileName\""); 
    } 
     
    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");    
    $range = 0; 
    $size = filesize($fileLocation); 
     
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) { 
        list($a, $range)=explode("=",$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']); 
        str_replace($range, "-", $range); 
        $size2=$size-1; 
        $new_length=$size-$range; 
        header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content"); 
        header("Content-Length: $new_length"); 
        header("Content-Range: bytes $range$size2/$size"); 
    } else { 
        $size2=$size-1; 
        header("Content-Range: bytes 0-$size2/$size"); 
        header("Content-Length: ".$size); 
    } 
         
    if ($size == 0 ) { die('Zero byte file! Aborting download');} 
    set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);  
    $fp=fopen("$fileLocation","rb"); 
     
    fseek($fp,$range); 
   
    while(!feof($fp) and (connection_status()==0)) 
    { 
        set_time_limit(0); 
        print(fread($fp,1024*$maxSpeed)); 
        flush(); 
        ob_flush(); 
        sleep(1); 
    } 
    fclose($fp); 
            
    return((connection_status()==0) and !connection_aborted()); 
}  

/* Implementation */ 
downloadFile('fileLocation','fileName.ext',900,false); 

?>
```

Now my issue is that when downloading large files (about 800 MB) I am only getting half of the file (about 440 MB) and I have no idea why this is. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or does anyone have an idea what I can do different?

As mentioned, I use [this function](http://www.awesomephp.com/?Tutorials*16/Download-file-with-resume,-stream-and-speed-options.html) combined with my script below.

```
    require_once 'func_downloadFile.php';

    // Get filename
    $filename = explode("/", $_GET['file']);
    $filename = $filename[count($filename)-1];

    $file_path = "downloads/" . $filename;

    if(file_exists($file_path)) {
        downloadFile($file_path, $filename, 900, false);
    }
    else {
        echo "File does not exist.";
    }
```

First the file is downloaded from my NAS onto my webserver and then sent to the client. If I use my script for downloading to the client I am only getting half of the file but if I download the file from my NAS to my webserver, then log into tmy webserver through and FTP client and download the file, I will get the whole file. So the issue is when sending from webserver to client (which is what `downloadFile()` does)

**EDIT:** I tried checking if `safe_mode` was on using `if(ini_get('safe_mode')){`
 which returned false. Therefore I tried adding the two lines below to set the timeout to unlimited but the result is the same.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
set_time_limit(0);
```

Comment: @cularis, it sounds possible but would there be a way to change that? As far as I know, I will have to change some property in the ini file, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set_time_limit will allow you to adjust the maximum execution time of the script 
see http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: I tried checking if `safe_mode` is on using `if(ini_get('safe_mode')){` and it returned false. Therefore I tried adding the two lines in my original post but the result is the same.

Comment: Does it tell you what the file size is when the download starts, I'm trying this using my server and some random files I have.

When the DL starts it tells me the download is (in this case) 350MB and then downloads the full file (no time out no nothing) how big are the files you're sending?

Comment: The file is 830 MB and it shows the correct size while downloading but stops between 300-400 MB.

Comment: It does say that in your original post (I should learn to read), What is your webserver running (OS wise not that it makes any difference I'm just exhausting everything)?
How do your files get from the NAS to the webserver (if it's done on the fly then there is a chance that only half the file is getting to the webserver)

Comment: My webserver should be running Linux. It's not really MY webserver - it's just a webhotel. The files are downloaded from the NAS to the webhotel using `ftp_get()`. I have checked if the whole file has been transferred to the webhotel and it has. I logged on to my webhotel using an FTP client, downloaded the file and it was all there.

Comment: Hmmm Apache has no download limit (not since 2.2) as far as I can see.

Comment: 1. see if the downloaded file is always an exact size (like 350M) but from your description it seems fairly randomised

2. Try reducing the download speed (it looks like you're calling a max dl speed of 900Kb/s(ish))

3.Try calling ini_set('memory_limit','128M'); But I really don't think that is the issue, I'm sorry but I'm really at an impasse beyond this point you may have to consider splitting the file out and serving it in chunks (Something like filename.tar.bz0 filename.tar.bz1 etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you are hitting the script execution time limit? (Default 30 seconds)

You can edit your function to reset the time limit in the loop...

```
while(!feof($fp) and (connection_status()==0)) {
    set_time_limit(30); 
    ...
}
```

You can't set the limit higher without editing php.ini, but putting this in the loop will reset it on each iteration of the loop.

Are there any entries in the httpd error log?

Comment: Using `set_time_limit` in `if($doStream == true) {` should not work as I am not streaming the files, meaning `$doStream` is `false`

Comment: My mistake, I meant the main loop `while(!feof($fp) and (connection_status()==0)) {`

Comment: I don't believe you can use ini_set in your script to make the total time of the script longer than what is set in php.ini. You can either increase the limit in php.ini or periodically reset the timer during the execution of your script with `set_time_limit`. each time you call `set_time_limit`, you will be resetting the timer.

Comment: IMHO periodical `set_time_limit` is a safer way to go. If you increase the time in php.ini that means that EVERY php script on your server that goes into a tail spin, will spin for a longer time. If you periodically reset the timer however, you are still protected from silly little mistakes that will cause an unintentional spin even in other parts of the same script.

Comment: That's a good point. It should be safer to set it in the loop instead of changing the value in php.ini. I just checked the script in the main loop and it turned out that `set_time_limit` was already being used with `0` as value. So it should be unlimited, right? It seems than `set_time_limit(30)` won't do the difference then.

Comment: I had to test it to be sure, but you are correct. My thinking was it might see setting it to "no limit" as higher than the php.ini limit and therefore ignore it, but I can successfully keep a loop alive for longer than 30 secs (my php.ini limit) so it is reseting the timer, even if only for the 30 seconds. So I would say that is probably not the problem. Could you check your HTTPD log and error files and see if there is anything there when this occurs? Any errors might be helpful and I would be particularly interested in the HTTP status in the log file if it is anything other than 200.

Comment: i have same problem and it is not execution time issue, file in total is only 1 MB big and downloaded is 160 bytes, what it could be?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your timeout settings.
The entry is called [max_execution_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) and you can find it in your php.ini file.
The standard is 30 second. (set_time_limit won't work in safe mode)

Comment: I tried checking if `safe_mode` is on using `if(ini_get('safe_mode')){` and it returned false. Therefore I tried adding the two lines in my original post but the result is the same.