# PHP Downloading File(s) outside webroot

Tags: php, header, download

I save many documents outside the webroot.

I want to click a link, that opens a new window (target="_blank"), and force download the file that's found.

Here's what I've got so far, but my results show gobble-de-gook in the browser popup, rather than forcing the download to the desktop:

```
function download($filelocation){

  $filename = basename($filelocation); 
  if (file_exists($filelocation)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename); 
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filelocation));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($filelocation);
    exit;
  }

}
```

In the new browser window I simply call that `download()` function with a specific path the the file.

It's definitely finding the file, but now I'm just wondering what I'm missing with header() to force the file through the browser.

Comment: Which browsers have you tried?

Comment: Ehm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724257/php-header-attach-avi-file

Comment: you have to tell the browser what the file application type is, so that it can call the appropriate handler.  for example,  is it a .jpg picture, or a .doc file?  ... like Vyktor says ...

Answer (score 1):

Missing this:

```
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
```

Comment: Tried this, and getting the same result.  I've even changed the content-type to reflect the actual file type.