# PHP save file from automatic save page

Tags: php

I am visiting one site, which already provide following functionality: When user browser visits this url, it will automatically prompt window to download containing file (video). In my script I need to download this attached file from this site to disk using php. I tried to use curl:

```
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

And also similar `file_get_contents` but it doesnt work for me. It get me only containing HTML on that site. Have you any idea how to save this file on the disk using php?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP header attach AVI-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724257/php-header-attach-avi-file)

Comment: I don't think, this is duplicate, because I am trying to 'invert' this question and emulate behavior of browser.

Comment: So send browser headers.... Can you clarify what you mean by "emulate this behavior of browser"?

Comment: Yes, I need to simply download this automatically downloading file and I need to do this with php. Can I do this by using headers?

Comment: This doesn't explain what you mean by "emulate this behavior of browser". The duplicate question shows you how to download the file.

Comment: Sorry, if I dont get it, but that question only shows how to set these headers to force browser to download this file. I need to download this file with php, from site, where is already set Content-Disposition:attachment header. Or am I wrong? By saying of emulation of browser behavior I meant to this php script behave as browser and download this file

Comment: You didn't think to change the last part of the answer to write the file to disk instead...?

Comment: I changed it. But is there a chance to get this attached file?

Answer (score -2):

One standard way that developers do this in PHP is to use the "header" method. After calling header, the page can output the video contents, which will prompt a user download.

See this example: [PHP header attach AVI-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724257/php-header-attach-avi-file)

Comment: If there is a duplicate, please flag the question to be closed as a duplicate, or post the link as a comment. This is not a valid answer within SO guidelines.

Comment: This may or may not be a duplicate, depending on the filetype, etc.

Comment: I an not sure if we understand each other, maybe problem is on my site, but I don't want to force my web site to prompt downloading window for user. I am trying to download this type of file from site that prompts this automatic window and I need to do this by using php.

Comment: Have you tried the "header" approach? What is it currently doing on your site?